# Why doesn't the `nonlocal` keyword propogate the outer-scoped variable to the calling module?

Tags: python, scope, pytest, monkeypatching, python-nonlocal

So this involves a maybe unusual chain of things:

**A.py**

```
from B import call

def make_call():
    print("I'm making a call!")
    call(phone_number="867-5309")
```

**B.py**

```
def call(phone_number):
    pass
```

**test_A.py**

```
import pytest

from A import make_call

@pytest.fixture
def patch_A_call(monkeypatch):
    number = "NOT ENTERED"
    number_list = []
    def call(phone_number):
        nonlocal number
        number = phone_number
        number_list.append(phone_number)

    monkeypatch.setattr("A.call", call)
    return (number, number_list)


def test_make_call(patch_A_call):
    make_call()

    print(f"number: {patch_A_call[0]}")
    print(f"number_list: {patch_A_call[1]}")
```

What's printed is:

```
number: NOT ENTERED
number_list: [867-5309]
```

I expected "867-5309" to be the value for both results.

I know that lists are passed by reference in Python—but I assumed that the `nonlocal` declaration would pass the variable along down the chain.

Why doesn't it work this way?

Comment: @larsks nope! that's just pytest syntax. i dunno how familiar you are with [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html), but accessing the requested fixture just accesses its return-value (in this case: a list)

Comment: Do you understand about Python's scoping rules, and in particular [lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope)? `patch_A_call` fixture just returns a tuple of (str, list).  The nonlocal keyword did apply, but it applied _within_ the scope of `patch_A_call`. It can't magically modify the tuple, which has already been returned _before_ you even invoke `make_call()`. If instead of returning `number` you return `lambda: number` (and then use this "getter" in your print function) then you'll see that the call did modify the nonlocal variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see how `call` is called, I think a simpler option is to replace it with a Mock object:

```
from unittest import mock

from A import make_call


@mock.patch('A.call')
def test_make_call(fake_call):
    make_call()
    assert fake_call.call_args.kwargs['phone_number'] == '867-5309'
```

Here, we're replacing `A.call` with a `unittest.mock.Mock` object. This gets called by `make_call`, and the call arguments are recorded by the Mock object for later inspection.

This requires substantially less code.

Note that I'm using an `assert` statement here, but you could instead print out or otherwise record the value of `phone_number` if that's your goal.

---

The primary problem with your solution is that your `patch_A_call` fixture is called once, **before** your `test_make_call` method executes.

So while the `nonlocal` keyword is working as intended...you never see the result, because that `return (number, number_list)` statement ran **before** you made the call to `make_call`.

You see the result in the list because a list is a "container" -- you add the number to it when calling `make_call`, and you can see the result because the returned list is the same object available from inside your patched `call` method.

---

For my solution, we don't have to use `mock.patch()`; we can rewrite your fixture like this:

```
import pytest
from unittest import mock

from A import make_call


@pytest.fixture
def patch_A_call(monkeypatch):
    call_recorder = mock.Mock()
    monkeypatch.setattr("A.call", call_recorder)
    return call_recorder


def test_make_call(patch_A_call):
    make_call()
    assert patch_A_call.call_args.kwargs["phone_number"] == "867-5309"
```

This accomplishes pretty much the same thing.

Comment: to make sure i'm understanding you correctly: if i wanted `number` to be accessible in the way i expect it to be, i'd have to use `nonlocal` somewhere in... `B` or something? (not that I intend to do this, i'm just making sure i understand the flow of things)

Comment: I don't think there's any good way to do what you want. With you current solution, using just `number_list` instead of `number` is probably the best idea (since, as you noted in your question, that gives you access to the value you want), but I think using a mock object and inspecting the call arguments is a cleaner solution.

Comment: i think that'd be cleaner in general too. my case specifically though is: the to-be-mocked- function needs to be mocked, and is used a bunch—but i only explicitly need the return value in *one* case. i'd rather use an `autouse` fixture than a decorator for every test

Comment: Note that I updated the question to show how to accomplish the same thing via your fixture instead of the `mock.patch` decorator :)